# Filling a CC field to email a pdf form from field

Tags: forms, pdf, acrobat, pdf-form

Trying to setup some forms for a Scout troop that fill in a variable email from PDF form fields.[File Download below]

The static emails are easy, but I want to find a javascript to pull data from the "tour" field to setup a variable for a CC send of the pdf.

Found this code in another forum, any help appreciated

[Download Here](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/13236635/ScoutCreditFormstest.pdf)

Comment: To be clearer - I want to add an email address to the "tour" field that will become the CC address.  That way, Tour Directors can know who pays, and the form will still also go to the treasurer.

Answer (score 0):

```
var cToAddr = "donovan_mcneil@imap.cc"
var cCCAddr = this.getField("tour").value;
var cSubLine = "Troop 497 Scout Credit"
this.mailDoc({bUI: true, cTo: cToAddr, cCc: cCCAddr, cSubject: cSubLine});
```